# Cannot import Firebase in CocoaPod

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I'm creating a CocoaPod from which I'd like to import Firebase. I get the error:

> "No such module 'Firebase'"

When I add `import Firebase` to a Swift file in my pod.

My CocoaPod Foo's pod spec file, `Foo.podspec`, contains:

```
s.dependency 'Firebase', '~> 3.6'
```

Comment: "I add import Firebase to a Swift file in my pod." Could you expain that? The `s.dependency` should only tell you when someone else use your pod that it will import if necessary (avoiding duplicate imports) of Firebase. But it's unclear if you by the "No such module" error, you mean that that's your use in your current pods. Declaring the s.dependency does do the import. You may have to use a podfile in your pod to set up necesary files for XCode to compile.

Comment: I should not have to duplicate my dependencies in the `Podfile` that consumes my CocoaPod.  Declaring the `s.dependency` ***should*** do the import

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a problem with the module mapping in the podspec made by Firebase for the latest version of their pod (see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6138).

I am currently working on a chat system based on Firebase that I have abstracted as a private CocoaPod. If I erase all traces of Firebase in my code/ podspec, all other Pods are imported flawlessly. I don't know that there is much we can do until this is fixed.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if you filed a ticket, so I went ahead and filed one.  Oddly, there's no way to share a URL for the ticket.  I'll keep this thread up to date with my exploits.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this same problem and the solution I settled on so that I could use firebase from inside both my development pod as well as apps using it was to setup the firebase sdk inside Xcode so that it can be found in the same way that a system framework is.

1. Download [the firebase sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks)
2. Move the frameworks you need into Xcode /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/
3. Setup your pod spec so that it knows where the frameworks are as well as add a few required dependencies.

   ```
   # Specify what libraries this depends on.
   s.libraries = [
     'c++', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'icucore', # FirebaseDatabase.
     'sqlite3', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'z', # FirebaseAnalytics.
   ]

   # Specify what frameworks this depends on.
   s.frameworks = [
     'AddressBook', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'AdSupport', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'CFNetwork', # FirebaseDatabase.
     'SafariServices', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'Security', # FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseAuth, FirebaseDatabase.
     'StoreKit', # FirebaseAnalytics.
     'SystemConfiguration', # FirebaseAnalytics, FirebaseDatabase.
     'FirebaseAnalytics',
     'FirebaseInstanceID',
     'FirebaseCore',
     'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics',
     'FirebaseNanoPB',
     'GoogleToolboxForMac',
     'FirebaseAuth',
     'GTMSessionFetcher',
     'FirebaseDatabase'
   ]
   s.xcconfig = { 'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/**' }

   # LDFLAGS required by Firebase dependencies.
   s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
     'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '$(inherited) -ObjC',
   }
   ```

This example only uses firebase Analytics, Auth and Database but I'm sure other frameworks could be added as well. It isn't the best solution but it works for my situation.